# How to select among 4 columns two consecutive with the max range and divide it between the max range found between either of the 4 columns

Tags: r

I have `df1` that summarises different datetimes over time and `df2` that summarises different water temperatures at different depths over time. I want to add a new column in `df1` called `Prop_rangeT` that for a specific datetime, is equal the maximum range between TWO CONSECUTIVE COLUMNS divided between the maximum range considering either of the four columns in `df2` for the same datetime than `df1`. As an example:

```
df1<- data.frame(DateTime=c("2016-08-01 08:01:17","2016-08-01 09:17:14","2016-08-01 10:29:31","2016-08-01 11:35:02","2016-08-01 12:22:45","2016-08-01 13:19:27","2016-08-01 14:58:17","2016-08-01 15:30:10"))
df1$DateTime<- as.POSIXct(df1$DateTime, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz= "UTC")
df2<- data.frame(DateTime=c("2016-08-01 08:00:00","2016-08-01 09:00:00","2016-08-01 10:00:00","2016-08-01 11:00:00","2016-08-01 12:00:00","2016-08-01 13:00:00","2016-08-01 14:00:00","2016-08-01 15:00:00"),T5=c(27.0,27.5,27.1,27.0,26.8,26.3,26.0,26.3),T15=c(23.0,23.4,23.1,22.7,22.5,21.5,22.0,22.3),T25=c(19.0,20.0,19.5,19.6,16.0,16.3,16.2,16.7),T35=c(16.0,16.0,16.5,16.7,16.3,16.7,16.9,16.7))
df2$DateTime<- as.POSIXct(df2$DateTime, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz= "UTC")

df1
             DateTime
1 2016-08-01 08:01:17
2 2016-08-01 09:17:14
3 2016-08-01 10:29:31
4 2016-08-01 11:35:02
5 2016-08-01 12:22:45
6 2016-08-01 13:19:27
7 2016-08-01 14:58:17
8 2016-08-01 15:30:10

df2
             DateTime   T5  T15  T25  T35
1 2016-08-01 08:00:00 27.0 23.0 19.0 16.0 # Here max range is between T35 ans T5 (11) and the max range between two consecutive columns is either T15 and T5 or T25 and T15 (4).
2 2016-08-01 09:00:00 27.5 23.4 20.0 16.0
3 2016-08-01 10:00:00 27.1 23.1 19.5 16.5
4 2016-08-01 11:00:00 27.0 22.7 19.6 16.7
5 2016-08-01 12:00:00 26.8 22.5 16.0 16.3
6 2016-08-01 13:00:00 26.3 21.5 16.3 16.7
7 2016-08-01 14:00:00 26.0 22.0 16.2 16.9 # In this case, max range is between T25 and T5 (9.8), and the max range between two consecutive columns correspond to T25 and T15 (5.8).
8 2016-08-01 15:00:00 26.3 22.3 16.7 16.7
```

How could I get the column `df1$Prop_rangeT` with the simplest code? As an example of what I would like to get:

```
df1
             DateTime Prop_rangeT
1 2016-08-01 08:01:17   0.3636364 # For instance, this is 4/11
2 2016-08-01 09:17:14   0,3565217
3 2016-08-01 10:29:31   0,3773585
4 2016-08-01 11:35:02   0.4174757
5 2016-08-01 12:22:45   0.6018519
6 2016-08-01 13:19:27   0.5200000
7 2016-08-01 14:58:17   0.5918367 # For instance, this is 5.8/9.8
8 2016-08-01 15:30:10   0.5833333
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First find columns which we are interested in to do max calculation (starting with "T"). Now for every row in those columns calculate the ratio of maximum difference in consecutive value and maximum difference in total value. Match the timestamp in `df1` and `df2` and get the corresponding ratio.

```
t_cols <- grep("^T", names(df2))


df2$ratio <- apply(df2[t_cols], 1, function(x) {
       max_consecutive <- max(-diff(x))
       new_x <- sort(x)
       max_total <- new_x[length(x)] - new_x[1]
       max_consecutive/max_total
})


df1$Prop_rangeT <- df2$ratio[match(lubridate::floor_date(df1$DateTime, "hour"), 
                                                          df2$DateTime)]


df1
#             DateTime Prop_rangeT
#1 2016-08-01 08:01:17   0.3636364
#2 2016-08-01 09:17:14   0.3565217
#3 2016-08-01 10:29:31   0.3773585
#4 2016-08-01 11:35:02   0.4174757
#5 2016-08-01 12:22:45   0.6018519
#6 2016-08-01 13:19:27   0.5200000
#7 2016-08-01 14:58:17   0.5918367
#8 2016-08-01 15:30:10   0.5833333
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `fuzzy_left_join`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(fuzzyjoin)
df1 %>%
    fuzzy_left_join(
        df2 %>%
            gather(key, val, -DateTime) %>%
            group_by(DateTime) %>%
            arrange(DateTime) %>%
            summarise(ratio = max(abs(c(0, diff(val))) / max(abs(diff(combn(x, 2)))))),
        by = "DateTime", match_fun = list(`>`)) %>%
    group_by(DateTime.x) %>%
    filter(DateTime.x - DateTime.y == min(DateTime.x - DateTime.y))
## A tibble: 8 x 3
## Groups:   DateTime.x [8]
#  DateTime.x          DateTime.y          ratio
#  <dttm>              <dttm>              <dbl>
#1 2016-08-01 08:01:17 2016-08-01 08:00:00 0.364
#2 2016-08-01 09:17:14 2016-08-01 09:00:00 0.373
#3 2016-08-01 10:29:31 2016-08-01 10:00:00 0.364
#4 2016-08-01 11:35:02 2016-08-01 11:00:00 0.391
#5 2016-08-01 12:22:45 2016-08-01 12:00:00 0.591
#6 2016-08-01 13:19:27 2016-08-01 13:00:00 0.473
#7 2016-08-01 14:58:17 2016-08-01 14:00:00 0.527
#8 2016-08-01 15:30:10 2016-08-01 15:00:00 0.509
```

Explanation: We reshape `df2` from wide to long, and calculate the maximal ratio of (absolute) difference of temperatures at consecutive depths and the maximum difference in temperatures measured at any depths. The rest is a fuzzy join on `DateTime`, where we select only those entries that are nearest in date for every `DateTime` in `df1`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this works. Nothing too fancy going on here. I wrote out each difference, then threw in some `rowwise` calculations.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df1 %>% 
  mutate(FloorDate = floor_date(DateTime, unit = "hour")) %>% 
  left_join(df2, by = c("FloorDate" = "DateTime")) %>% 
  mutate(ConsDiff1 = abs(T5 - T15),
         ConsDiff2 = abs(T15 - T25),
         ConsDiff3 = abs(T25 - T35),
         AllDiff1 = abs(T5 - T25),
         AllDiff2 = abs(T5 - T35),
         AllDiff3 = abs(T15 - T35)) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(MaxConsDiff = max(ConsDiff1, ConsDiff2, ConsDiff3),
         MaxAllDiff = max(ConsDiff1, ConsDiff2, ConsDiff3, AllDiff1, AllDiff2, AllDiff3),
         Prop_rangeT = MaxConsDiff / MaxAllDiff) %>% 
  select(DateTime, Prop_rangeT)

# A tibble: 8 x 2
  DateTime            Prop_rangeT
  <dttm>                    <dbl>
1 2016-08-01 08:01:17       0.364
2 2016-08-01 09:17:14       0.357
3 2016-08-01 10:29:31       0.377
4 2016-08-01 11:35:02       0.417
5 2016-08-01 12:22:45       0.602
6 2016-08-01 13:19:27       0.520
7 2016-08-01 14:58:17       0.592
8 2016-08-01 15:30:10       0.583
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#Assuming that df1 and df2 fit by row 
(df1$Prop_rangeT <- apply(df2[,2:5], 1, function(x) {max(abs(diff(x)))/diff(range(x))}))
#0.3636364 0.3565217 0.3773585 0.4174757 0.6018519 0.5200000 0.5918367 0.5833333

#In case they don't fit by row matching them e.g. by Year, Month, Day and Hour
df1$Prop_rangeT <- apply(df2[,2:5], 1, function(x) {
 max(abs(diff(x)))/diff(range(x))})[match(format(df1$DateTime, "%Y%m%d%H"), format(df2$DateTime, "%Y%m%d%H"))]
```

Comment: They fit in this example, but it usually doesn't fit, so I would need first of all to find the row in df2 that match with the row in df1 regarding datetime.

Comment: I have updated for this case using Year, Month, Day and Hour as datetime for matching.

Comment: Thank you very much for your tiime, but it didn't work! When I launched it, R showed "Error: inesperado '}' in "max(abs(diff(x)))/diff(range(x))}"

Comment: You have to use both lines not only the one starting with max.